# Running Multiple .NET Core 2.2 APIs Locally with IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

This is my first time attempting to build out an API with many different separate API projects within one solution using .NET Core 2.2. I'm really having trouble configuring all of the different projects to run so that I can debug and run my Angular application locally.

Let's say I have three API projects within my solution. I want localhost/api-one, localhost/api-two, localhost/api-three. I want each to be running consistently, and I'd like them to each have their own Application Pool.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's driving me nuts. Some problems I'm running into a lot:

- Service is unavailable and I need to physically go into VS and run the specific API, then go back to my application and try again
- Application Pool keeps getting changed (incrementally adding a number to the end) which messes up my permissions when hitting my SQL database
- When I rebuild my project, it says that it can't copy the DLLs to the bin folder because they're tied up by the IIS worker process. The only thing that seems to work for this is killing IIS completely, and then restarting.. but that seems to be when I get the new App Pool with a new number attached

Is there a trick for this setup with .NET Core? I've done this with .NET before and never had any problems. I realize .NET Core's way of interacting with IIS is drastically different, but I feel like I have to be missing something obvious.